# In python interpreter, 3.14.__class__ works but 3.__class__ does not

Tags: python-3.x

When checking the type of int objects in python3 interpreter below error is encounterd:

```
>>> 3.14.__class__
<class 'float'>

>>> 3.__class__
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3.__class__
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Whereas below code works:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> x.__class__
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
>>> type(3.14)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(3)
<class 'int'>
>>> isinstance(3.14, float)
True
>>> isinstance(3, float)
False
>>> isinstance(3.14, int)
False
>>> isinstance(3, int)
True
```